# How to sent data from form to backend? [Java]

Tags: java, json, spring, model-view-controller

how to send data from the  form view to the backend? I want to use the collected data to create a JSON request.

```
@Controller
public class ControllerClass {

    Connect connect = new Connect();

    @RequestMapping(value = "/Search", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView showForm() {
        return new ModelAndView("Forms", "FlightDTO", new FlightDTO());
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/connect", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String submit(@Valid @ModelAttribute("FlightDTO") FlightDTO flightDTO,
                         BindingResult result, ModelMap model) {
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return "error.jsp";
        }
        return connect.connect();
    }
}
```

View class collecting data.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>Getting Started: Handling Form Submission</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
<h1>Form</h1>
<form action="#" th:action="@{/connect}" th:object="${FlightDTO}" method="post">
    <p>Orgin: <input type="text" th:field="*{Origin}" /></p>
    <p>Departure: <input type="text" th:field="*{Departure}" /></p>
    <p>DateFrom: <input type="text" th:field="*{DateFrom}" /></p>
    <p>DateTo: <input type="text" th:field="*{DateTo}" /></p>
    <p>Currency: <input type="text" th:field="*{Currency}" /></p>



    <p><input type="submit" value="Submit" /> <input type="reset" value="Reset" /></p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Class responsible for consume data JSON.

```
public class Connect  {

    public String connect() {
        String output = null;

        try {
            UrlBuilder urlBuilder = new UrlBuilder();
            urlBuilder.ulr();

            System.out.println("URL String : " + urlBuilder.ulr());
            URL url = new URL(urlBuilder.ulr());
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection() ;
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");

            if (conn.getResponseCode() != 200) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP Error code : " + conn.getResponseCode());
            }

            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            String inputLine;
            StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(inputLine);
            }
            in.close();
            output = response.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception Flight:- " + e);
        }


        return output;
    }
}
```

Class that is responsible for collecting data from the view

```
public class FlightDTO {
    private String dateFrom;

private String dateTo;

@Size(min = 2, max = 10)
private String origin;
@Size(min = 2, max = 10)
private String departure;
@Size(min = 2, max = 4)
private String currency;
```

My URL builder Class responsible for build request.

```
public class UrlBuilder extends FlightDTO {

    private String key = "47c5ebee552ce27c902e7521b6ef3858";


    public String ulr( ) {
        String connectUrlString =
                "http://api.travelpayouts.com/v1/prices/cheap?origin="
                        + getOrigin() + "&destination=" + getDeparture() +
                        "&depart_date=" + getDateFrom() +
                        "&currency=" + getCurrency() +
                        "&return_date=" + getDateTo() +
                        "&token=" + key;
        return connectUrlString ;
    }



}
```

I tried to solve my problem in many ways. Unfortunately to no avail, that's why I decided to create a thread. I could not find a similar problem. I was probably looking for a bad one. However, I do not know how to google

I get null response :

```
http://api.travelpayouts.com/v1/prices/cheap?origin=null&destination=null&depart_date=null&currency=null&return_date=null&token=47c5ebee552ce27c902e7521b6ef3858
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Above code will not work as you are creating new `UrlBuilder` object which will not have any values instead of passing `flightDTO` object from the controller.

> Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/connect", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String submit(@Valid @ModelAttribute("FlightDTO") FlightDTO flightDTO,
                         BindingResult result, ModelMap model) {
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return "error.jsp";
        }
        return connect.connect(flightDTO); //passing flightDTO object received from form
    }
```

> Connect

```
public String connect(FlightDTO flightDTO) { //Added new parameter to recevice flightDTO
        String output = null;

        try {
            UrlBuilder urlBuilder = new UrlBuilder();
            urlBuilder.setOrigin(flightDTO.getOrigin());
            urlBuilder.setDestination(flightDTO.getDestination());
            urlBuilder.setDateFrom(flightDTO.getDateFrom());
            urlBuilder.setDateTo(flightDTO.getDateTo());
            ......//Set other required values
            urlBuilder.ulr();

            System.out.println("URL String : " + urlBuilder.ulr());
            ......//other code    
        }
}
```

Comment: Everything is fine, but I am wondering ... Is it correctly schema what I did ? Maybe is pattern for that ? :)

Comment: @Grafik Current design of your application is not correct. I would recommend you to make some changes.

Comment: Ok, what for example ?

Comment: Many changes required. I would suggest you to create different question share the link here. I will list down all the changes there. It would be difficult to list those down here

Comment: Hi! Help me if You wish https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56254950/i-am-wondering-how-can-i-improve-my-code . Thank You very much. I am appreciate it ! :)